# Properties of Lie derivative

Tags: derivatives, lie-algebras

Let's have Lie derivative:
$$
L_{V}\varphi = V^{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\varphi , \quad L_{V}A_{\mu} = V^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} + (\partial_{\mu}V^{\nu})A_{\nu}. 
$$
How to show that for scalar and vector fields
$$
L_{V}L_{U} - L_{U}L_{V} = L_{[U, V]}, [U, V]^{\nu} = U^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}V^{\nu} - V^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}U^{\nu}?
$$

An attempt to prove equality for vector field.

$$
L_{[U, V]}A_{\mu} = [U, V]^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} + (\partial_{\mu}[U, V]^{\nu})A_{\nu} = 
$$
$$
=[U, V]^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} + (\partial_{\mu}(U^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}V^{\nu} - V^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}U^{\nu}))A_{\nu}. \qquad (.1)
$$
By the other way [edited],
$$
(L_{U}L_{V} - L_{V}L_{U})A_{\mu} = L_{U}(V^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu}(V^{\nu})A_{\nu}) - L_{V}(U^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu}(U^{\nu})A_{\nu})=
$$
$$
= U^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}[V^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu}(V^{\nu})A_{\nu}] + \partial_{\mu}(U^{\alpha})[V^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} + \partial_{\alpha}(V^{\nu})A_{\nu}] -
$$
$$
-V^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}[U^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu}(U^{\nu})A_{\nu}] - \partial_{\mu}(V^{\alpha})[U^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} + \partial_{\alpha}(U^{\nu})A_{\nu}]=
$$
$$
=[U, V]^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu}(U^{\alpha})V^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} + U^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}(\partial_{\mu}(V^{\nu})A_{\nu}) + \partial_{\mu}(U^{\alpha})\partial_{\alpha} (V^{\nu})A_{\nu} -
$$
$$
- \partial_{\mu}(V^{\alpha})U^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} - V^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}(\partial_{\mu}(U^{\nu})A_{\nu}) - \partial_{\mu}(V^{\alpha})\partial_{\alpha}(U^{\nu})A_{\nu}. \qquad (.2)
$$
But I don't know how to make $(.2)$ equal to $(.1)$.

Edit.

By rewriting the second summand in $(.1)$ as
$$
\partial_{\mu}(U^{\nu})\partial_{\nu}(V^{\alpha})A_{\alpha} + \partial_{\mu}(U^{\nu})V^{\alpha}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} + U^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}(\partial_{\mu}(V^{\alpha})A_{\alpha}) - \partial_{\mu}(V^{\nu})\partial_{\nu}(U^{\alpha})A_{\alpha} - \partial_{\mu}(V^{\nu})U^{\alpha}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} -V^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}(\partial_{\mu}(U^{\alpha})A_{\alpha})
$$
I got
$$
[L_{[U, V]} - (L_{U}L_{V} - L_{V}L_{U})]A_{\mu} =
$$

$$
=\partial_{\mu}(U^{\nu})V^{\alpha}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} - \partial_{\mu}(V^{\nu})U^{\alpha}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} - \partial_{\mu}(U^{\alpha})V^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} + \partial_{\mu}(V^{\alpha})U^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha},
$$
which isn't equal to zero.

Comment: Cross-posted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83865/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- On scalars

$$L_V(L_U(\phi)):=v^{\rho}\partial_\rho u^{\nu}\partial_\nu\phi+
v^{\rho}u^{\nu}\partial^2_{\rho\nu}\phi; $$

$$L_U(L_V(\phi)):=u^{\rho}\partial_\rho v^{\nu}\partial_\nu\phi+
u^{\rho}v^{\nu}\partial^2_{\rho\nu}\phi=(\text{repeated indices})=\\ 
u^{\nu}\partial_\nu v^{\rho}\partial_\rho\phi+
u^{\nu}v^{\rho}\partial^2_{\rho\nu}\phi.$$

$$L_{[U,V]}(\phi):=[U,V]^{\rho}\partial_\rho \phi=
u^{\nu}\partial_\nu v^{\rho}\partial_\rho\phi
-v^{\nu}\partial_\nu u^{\rho}\partial_\rho\phi=(\text{repeated indices})=\\ 
u^{\nu}\partial_\nu v^{\rho}\partial_\rho\phi
-v^{\rho}\partial_\rho u^{\nu}\partial_\nu\phi$$

i.e. $L_U\circ L_V-L_V\circ L_U=L_{[U,V]}.$

- On vector fields

$$L_{[U,V]}(A_\mu)=u^{\rho}\partial_\rho v^{\nu}\partial_\nu A_\mu-
v^{\rho}\partial_\rho u^{\nu}\partial_\nu A_\mu+
\partial_\mu(u^{\rho}\partial_\rho v^{\nu}-v^{\rho}\partial_\rho u^{\nu})A_\nu,$$

$$L_U(L_V(A_\mu)):=u^{\rho}\partial_\rho B_{\mu}+
\partial_\mu u^\rho B_\rho,$$

with $B_\mu=v^\nu\partial_\nu A_\mu+\partial_\mu v^\nu A_\nu$ and similarly for $B_\rho$. Similarly

$$L_V(L_U(A_\mu)):=v^{\rho}\partial_\rho C_{\mu}+
\partial_\mu v^\rho C_\rho,$$

with $C_\mu=u^\nu\partial_\nu A_\mu+\partial_\mu u^\nu A_\nu$ and similarly for $C_\rho$.

The identity on vector fields is then proven by a bit long but straightforward computation.

- Edit: on the OP computations

Two little remarks. In the computations leading to .2) the last term in the r.h.s of the second equality has a wrong sign (it should be a minus).

The first term in the last line of the same sequence of computations, i.e.  $-V^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}(U^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}) $ should not be.

Removing such term, we arrive at

$$L_{[U,V]}(A_\mu)-L_U(L_V(A_\mu))-L_V(L_U(A_\mu))=
U^{\alpha}\partial_{\mu}V^{\nu}\partial_\alpha A_{\nu}  - V^{\alpha}\partial_{\mu} U^{\nu}\partial_{\alpha}A_{\nu}+
\\
\partial_{\mu}U^{\alpha}V^{\nu}\partial_\nu A_{\alpha}
-\partial_{\mu}V^{\alpha} U^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha};$$

the r.h.s. of the above equality is equal to $0$: one needs to exchange the repeated indices $\nu\leftrightarrow \alpha$ in the last 2 terms to finish the proof.

Comment: if the OP needs more details on the vector case, I will edit the answer. The strategy for the computations is similar, though.

Comment: Thanks. 

I tried to do analogical things for vector case and only get expressions $(.1)$ and $(.2)$. Can you help?

Comment: Hallo @JohnTaylor. Do you need more details? Can you finish the proof? Please, follow the notation with $B\mu$ and $C\mu$. I think it simplifies the subsequent computations

Comment: Why did you write that 
$$
L_{V}A_{\mu} = v^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} = B_{\mu}
$$ 
instead of
$$
L_{V}A_{\mu} = v^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu}(v^{\nu})A_{\nu} = B_{\mu},
$$
as I used when I was trying to prove equality?

Comment: ...because I missed a piece in the definition of $B\mu$ by copy & paste (and similarly for $C\mu$). I edit it now, thanks.

Comment: Okay. But I carried out similar calculations and they led me to expression $(.2)$. I can't make it equal to $(.1)$. I already substituted the expressions for $C_{\mu}, B_{\mu}$ into it, so the expression is maximally simplified (as I can do).

Comment: So can you compute your expression and then compare it with $(.2)$, if you please? I think that in $(.2)$ there are 2 summands which are not present in $(.1)$.

Comment: I added two lines into the my attempt of derivation for greater clearness.

Comment: Ok, I will try it and edit my answer in the next hour :)

Comment: Hallo @JohnTaylor, I have done it. Please, feel free to upvote and flag the answer if it is useful to you. Byez

Comment: Hmmm. By correcting my derivation according to your instructions I got
$$
[L_{[U, V]} - (L_{U}L_{V} - L_{V}L_{U})]A_{\mu} = 
$$
$$
=\partial_{\mu}(U^{\nu})V^{\alpha}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} - \partial_{\mu}(V^{\nu})U^{\alpha}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} - \partial_{\mu}(U^{\alpha})V^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} + \partial_{\mu}(V^{\alpha})U^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha}.
$$
But it isn't like your summands. Meanwhile, they should be equal.

Comment: The second summand expansion of 1.) does not convince me: such summand is of the form  $\partial_\mu(...)A_\nu,$ where the partial derivative acts only on $(...)$, and not also on $A_\nu$. It is equal to $\partial_\mu U^\alpha \partial_\alpha V^\nu A_\nu+U^\alpha (\partial_\nu\partial_\alpha V^\nu) A_\nu -\partial_\mu V^\alpha \partial_\alpha U^\nu A_\nu- V^\alpha (\partial_\mu\partial_\alpha U^\nu) A_\nu $. With this expansion you can arrive at the thesis.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it in form
$$
\partial_{\mu}(U^{\nu})\partial_{\nu}(V^{\alpha})A_{\alpha} + \partial_{\mu}(U^{\nu})V^{\alpha}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} + U^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}(\partial_{\mu}(V^{\alpha})A_{\alpha}) - \partial_{\mu}(V^{\nu})\partial_{\nu}(U^{\alpha})A_{\alpha} - \partial_{\mu}(V^{\nu})U^{\alpha}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} -V^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}(\partial_{\mu}(U^{\alpha})A_{\alpha}),
$$
where I already acted by $\partial_{\alpha}$ on field $V, U$ and on $A_{\nu}$ separately.

Comment: But $(L_{U}L_{V} - L_{V}L_{U})A_{\mu}$ contains summands like $\partial_{\mu}(U^{\alpha})V^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha}$, which can't be equal to any summand from expression above (some summands are "destructed" by each other).

Comment: the term you wrote in your last comment is one of those which sum to zero using the trick $\nu\leftrightarrow \alpha$ in my answer. Please, check again the expansion of 1.) and/or my computations and use that trick: the results is near!

Comment: In summands like $U^{\alpha}(\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\alpha}V^{\nu})A_{\nu}$ derivative $\partial_{\alpha}$ acts also on $A_{\nu}$, doesn't it?

Comment: nope...only on $V^\nu$

Comment: But why? Excuse me, I don't understand that.

Comment: It is only notation, nothing more. You can help yourself in computations always writing the round brackets whenever you deal with products.

Comment: So, in expression $(\partial_{\mu}(U^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}V^{\nu} - V^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}U^{\nu}))A_{\nu}$ derivative $\partial_{\alpha}$ acts only on $U^{\nu}, V^{\nu}$?

Comment: yes, it is like that @JohnTaylor :-)

Comment: Excuse me for dull questions. The final one: in $(.2)$ there are two summands, $-\partial_{\mu}(V^{\alpha})U^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} - \partial_{\mu}(U^{\alpha})V^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha}$, which won't be "destructed" by the summands from $L_{[U, V]} A_{\mu}$:
$$
[L_{[U, V]} - L_{U}L_{V} - L_{V}L_{U}]A_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu}(V^{\alpha})U^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha} - \partial_{\mu}(U^{\alpha})V^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\alpha}.
$$
What to do with them? Why didn't you have them?

Comment: I have them: they are (up to a sign) the last two terms in the last string of eqs. in my answer (in the Edit section). I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I stupidly did not notice the order of the indices in the expression $(.2)$.